# load all scripts in _Layout.cshtml as one bundle?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm writing a web tool using C#, HTML and JavaScript code based on the MVC pattern and I was wondering if it is smart (page load time, traffic, etc.) to load all needed scripts in the *_Layout.cshtml*.

Is there a difference in bundling all scripts together and load them in the head section of the *_Layout.cshtml* or load them in the actual views when needed?

Is there a best practice for this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best strategy is to "load what you really need". You should bundle all shared scripts and styles on one side and load that on the layout, and then create separate bundles for each view to load only what will be used on that particular page.

The difference would be that you will require more bundling configuration (as you would have one bundle per view), but IMHO, you will gain a lot more in a better code organization and avoid downloading unnecessary files.

Of course this all depends of what kind of application you are developing. But if you have all in one bundle and the project gets larger, it will be very difficult to later change the strategy as you will need to review all the dependencies on each view.

In terms of page load/traffic, it is clear that this strategy is better as the client will download only the files which are needed.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful explanation.

Comment: You are welcome, I went through the same dilemma once :). If you think this answers your question, please mark it as answered. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can load script bundles in a view like this

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/movie")  
}
```